# remove time from date field in db2

Tags: db2

This is the date column I am using to get date

```
(CAST(substr(CAST(q2.hedte AS VARCHAR(8)),1,4) || '-' || substr(CAST(q2.hedte AS VARCHAR(8)),5,2) || '-' || 
substr(CAST(q2.hedte AS VARCHAR(8)),7,2) AS date)) As FLD5
```

However, this is also getting me time. How do I get rid of time?

Comment: What's the db2 platform and version?
If it's db2 for LUW then:
Do you use Oracle compatibility feature?
`select name, value from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name like '%compat%';`
What tool do you use to run the query?

Comment: I am using SqlDbx.

Comment: Are you actually getting a time value, or is it just your query tool formatting a DATE as a TIMESTAMP?  Try casting the result to a CHAR.  E.g.   `CAST(CAST(substr(CAST(q2.hedte AS VARCHAR(8)),1,4) || '-' || substr(CAST(q2.hedte AS VARCHAR(8)),5,2) || '-' || 
substr(CAST(q2.hedte AS VARCHAR(8)),7,2) AS date) as VARCHAR(30))`

Answer (score 0):

When using Db2 in Oracle compatibility mode, DATEs are actually TIMESTAMPs. That is how Oracle works, and so is how Db2 has to work to. It does mean that you can't then create proper DATE only columns.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0053667.html

So short of converting your DATE that is really a TIMESTAMP into e.g. CHAR(10), you can't "get rid of the time".

E.g. try this

```
SUBSTR(TO_DATE(q2.hedte,'YYYYMMDD'),1,10)
```

Comment: It returns: `SQL0171 - Argument 1 of function TO_DATE not valid.`

Comment: What Db2 platform and version are you using? Also are you using Oracle Compatibility?  Although the point of my answer was the `SUBSTR()` not the `TO_DATE` you can use your long concatenation if you prefer

Comment: also what data type is q2.hedte ?   My query works for Db2 LUW 11.1.3.3,.